# Continuous Horizontal CSS Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have a Create-React-app project that requires me to have some information constantly scroll across the screen.  My current implementation:

```js
 import React from 'react'
import './styles/animation.css'


const Tickerbar = (props) => {
  const displayNameStyle = {
    color:'white',
  }

  const midStyle = {
    color:'#CDBFBF',
    marginRight:'20px'
  }
  const displayNames = Object.keys(props.tickers)
  const displayNameAndMid = displayNames.map(cusip => {
    return(
        <span key={cusip}>
          <span style={displayNameStyle}>
            <b>{cusip.split('/').join('.')}: </b>
          </span>

          <span style={midStyle}>
            <b>{(props.tickers[cusip]).toFixed(2)}</b>
          </span>
        </span>
  )
  })
  return(
    <div className="marquee">
      <p>
        {displayNameAndMid}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Tickerbar;
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 51px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.marquee p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 100s linear 1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: marquee 100s linear 1s infinite;
    color:white;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
```

The problem with this however is that the text scrolls across, then when it ends, I can see it start up again.  Ideally, as the text is ending on the left side of the screen, it will start scrolling in again on the right side of the screen.  I've seen some implementations that work by writing the text twice, and having the second set of text start scrolling halfway through the animation time, but when I try this the letters end up on top of each other and are unreadable.

Comment: what is b? There is no native b tag?

Comment: @RachelGallen it's just a bold p tag - so to speak... but to your point - yes in the css it p and the mark up it's b...

Comment: @SakoBu oh right, I see .. yes that should really be a p tag , with a 'strong' class included in the style of the span...